# Run Angular Material Demo Code

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material

Trying to run the [Angular Material Basic Expansion Panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples) code, just to test it.

1. I hit the `Edit In StackBlitz button` [image]
2. Takes me [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/pbpxovolyny?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts)
3. I `Export` the code [image]
4. Unzip
5. Change directory and `npm install`
6. `ng serve`

But I get errors: 
[image]

So I google the error, and try [this solution](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9307#issuecomment-359264655).

When I rerun, I get this error: 
[image]

I google that, and try [this solution](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5920#issuecomment-293908321), changing main.ts, but I get the same error.

How can I get the example to run?

Comment: Why is this so hard? Is that your question? If coding was easy, everyone would do it. :)

Comment: lol my question is how to run Angular Materials demo code...

Comment: why don't you just edit it within stackblitz? It runs embedded visual studio code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the version of angular-cli

```
In your package.json change Ex,

original:

"@angular/cli": "1.5.0",

new:

"@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
```

you see ^1.0.2 it means to install version 1.0.2 or the latest minor or patch version such as 1.1.0.

The trick is the symbol ^

Do as @mauricio said: platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(this.AppModule);

Delete your node modules folder and do npm install, ng serve

Give it a try

This problem was solved on angular-cli by updating to 1.6.5

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this line with this line.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

with this one and it works like a charm.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(this.AppModule);
```